# Typescript property decorator - Need help to understand how the following happens?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I was just experimenting with Typescript property decorators. But, I could not understand the behavior of the following code :

```
function dec(hasRole: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyName: string) {
        let val = target[propertyName];
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
            get() { return val; },
            set(value) { val = hasRole; }
        });
    }
}

class Hey {
    age: number;

    @dec(true)
    hasRole: boolean = false;

    constructor(age: number) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

let ob = new Hey(22);
console.log(ob);
```

//Actual Output:

```
age: 22
hasRole: true
__proto__:
  constructor: class Hey
  hasRole: true
  get hasRole: ƒ get()
  set hasRole: ƒ set(value)
  __proto__: Object
```

The result I expected was:
*1. OwnProperty -> hasRole = false 
2. Prototype property -> hasRole = true.*
As 'target' in decorator argument provides the constructor function for static members or prototype of the class for instance members.

Could someone explain me this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand it clearly you should take a look at the [transpiled version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYQBQAsCGBnAJTgBtUAuRAIzhNRzAEpEBvAKEQ8QCdUoQukoSLASIMUHFwDmvCvQCeAGkQAHLnBWouUeQDkcAW3KI8ULjDBSmbTrcSkoiAG45iiALyIJ03gG01Glo6%20kYAugDc7HYcAPKUAFboUAB0aMAWqAAK6pra8uKSMlDKAbnBhqjKNtF2RRjW3Lz8SC7E4YgAvopRNZx4vBitIKgNrR6IuIS07R09dh0Mkbazs6wQxPh4iAASqPIsczgyFGAgBpRakXMAAmiYZsMMc5NEpBTUtPTjwK79V7YQBCmLggaBwLgYI7GU7nLTWOa2KBYGB4ZJQ8ZQpacFasVgORBwSjjMCoADuOz2GAATFTFmsgbRksQ4FIMITFkA)

```
function dec(hasRole) {
    return function (target, propertyName) {
        let val = target[propertyName];
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
            get() { return val; },
            set(value) { val = hasRole; }
        });
    };
}
class Hey {
    constructor(age) {
        this.hasRole = false;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
__decorate([
    dec(true)
], Hey.prototype, "hasRole", void 0);
let ob = new Hey(22);
console.log(ob);
```

From the code above it should be clear that **class is decorated first and only then a new instance is created**

It means that at the time constructor is being executed `hasRole` is already defined in Prototype hence assigning `this.hasRole` to anything doesn't have any effect: it's always assigned to `hasRole` parameter in decorator(which is `true`)

Comment: Okay, I think I understood it. So, if a getter setter with the same name is already attached in the prototype of the class, then while creation of the instance, that property in the instance will have the value set by the setter. Right??? Btw, thanks for explaining simply.